# Account wide achievements, pets, and mounts - cross region

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have one Battle.net account with three WoW accounts - two of these are EU and one of them is US.

Currently only one of the EU accounts is active and enabled.

If I were to reactivate the other EU account and the US account, would my achievement progress, mounts and battle pets be available on both of the EU accounts and the US account, just the EU accounts, or just the account that is currently active?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just the EU accounts.

[Here](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/6412403620) you can find a Blue answer on the official forums explaining that achievements, pets and mounts can only be shared by same-region accounts.